# Codeigniter - Check if a database connection has been configured

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter configured to use multiple databases. For some customers, we need to query an additional database so this is a matter of:

```
if( isConfigured(database) )
    foo();
```

However, the attempts I have made have either given the same result whether or not the db is configured in `databases.php`, or throws an error.

I have attempted the following:

```
if( $this->load->database('optional') == FALSE )
```

Which raises the error `You have specified an invalid database connection group`

```
try( $this->load->database('optional') )
{
    foo();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
     doNothing();
}
```

Which raises the same error

The documentation states that `$this->load->database('optional', TRUE)` returns the connection ID however I cannot check this as the code errors out before returning a value.

I was expecting to be able to check whether or not a property had been set, e.g. `$this->config->item('db')['optional']` but this would be largely guesswork to determine how to access the correct property

I have also looked into the `dbutil` class but this only applies to databases which have already established a connection.

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309468/you-have-specified-an-invalid-database-connection-group-codeigniter-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543855/codeigniter-multidatabse-connect-error

Comment: I already have 2 databases configured and working, but a 3rd is optional

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['db1']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db1']['username'] = 'root';
$db['db1']['password'] = '';
$db['db1']['database'] = 'mydatabase';
$db['db1']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db1']['dbprefix'] = '';

$this->load->database('db1',TRUE);
```

Comment: `$this->load->database('optional', TRUE)` returns the connection ID however I cannot check this as the code errors out before returning a value.